# AutoLisp-Quick sort for coordinates

Tags: lisp, quicksort, autolisp

I have tried to sort (using quicksort) coordinate list based on the x-coordinates(getting ascending order based on x-coordinates). But my quicksort goes into a infinite loop(it keeps compiling, since autolisp, I dont have a error cause). Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

```
(defun qd:partition (sp low high)
  (cond
    ((null sp) nil)
    (t
     (setq pivot (car (nth high sp)))
     (setq i -1)
     (setq j 0)
     (while (< j (- (length sp) 2))
       (if (<= (car (nth j sp)) pivot)
     (progn
     (setq i (1+ i))
     (qd:swap (nth j sp) (nth i sp))
     )
     )
       (setq j (1+ j))
       )
     (qd:swap (nth (+ i 1) sp) (nth high sp))
     )
    )
  (+ i 1)
  )
(defun qd:quicksort_x (sp low high)
  (if (< low high)
    (progn
      (setq part (qd:partition sp low high))
      (qd:quicksort_x sp low (1- part))
      (qd:quicksort_x sp (1+ part) high)
      )
    )
  )
   
(defun qd:swap (g h)
  (setq temp g)
  (setq g h)
  (setq h temp)
  )
```

I call it with:

```
  (setq high (- (length sp) 1))
  (princ (quicksort_x sp low high))
```

FYI the list with the co-ordiantes looks like

*((112040.0 -34649.7 0.0)
(112004.0 -34641.7 0.0)
(112134.0 -34649.7 0.0)
(112098.0 -34641.7 0.0)
(112000.0 -34773.7 0.0)
(112000.0 -34881.7 0.0)
(111946.0 -34801.7 0.0))*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Side stepping the problems, I suggest looking into the `vl-sort` function. This will shorten the amount of code you will need to write. Most of the time, lambda functions don't get their own variables. However, doing so helps me see how the process flows.

```lisp
;; Sorts X-Coordinates in assending order
(defun x_cord_accend (lCords / fcnLambda)
    
    ;; Anonymous, local function
    (setq fcnLambda 
        (function (lambda (lEntry1 lEntry2 / rXCord1 rXCord2)
            (setq rXCord1 (car lEntry1))
            (setq rXCord2 (car lEntry2))
            (< rXCord1 rXCord2)
        ));function<-lambda
    );setq

    ;; Sorting command
    (vl-sort lCords fcnLambda)
);x_cord_sort

;; Sorts Y-Coordinates in assending order
(defun y_cord_accend (lCords / fcnLambda)
    
    ;; Anonymous, local function
    (setq fcnLambda 
        (function (lambda (lEntry1 lEntry2)
            (< (cadr lEntry1)(cadr lEntry2))
        ));function<-lambda
    );setq

    ;; Sorting command
    (vl-sort lCords fcnLambda)
);y_cord_sort

;; Sorts Z-Coordinates in assending order
(defun z_cord_accend (lCords / fcnLambda)
    
    ;; Anonymous, local function
    (setq fcnLambda 
        (function (lambda (lEntry1 lEntry2)
            (< (caddr lEntry1)(caddr lEntry2))
        ));function<-lambda
    );setq

    ;; Sorting command
    (vl-sort lCords fcnLambda)
);z_cord_sort

;; User defines which coordinates to use
(defun cord_sort_accend (lCords iCord bReverse / fcnLambda lReturn)
    
    ;; Anonymous, local function
    (setq fcnLambda 
        (function (lambda (lEntry1 lEntry2)
            (< (nth iCord lEntry1) (nth iCord lEntry2))
        ));function<-lambda
    );setq

    ;; Sorting command
    (setq lReturn (vl-sort lCords fcnLambda))
    (if bReverse (reverse lReturn) lReturn); Return condition
);cord_sort_accend
```

These functions return the following information:

```lisp
(setq lTemp `((112040.0 -34649.7 0.0) (112004.0 -34641.7 0.0) (112134.0 -34649.7 0.0) (112098.0 -34641.7 0.0) (112000.0 -34773.7 0.0) (112000.0 -34881.7 0.0) (111946.0 -34801.7 0.0)))

(setq xCord (x_cord_accend lTemp))
((111946.0 -34801.7 0.0) (112000.0 -34773.7 0.0) (112000.0 -34881.7 0.0) (112004.0 -34641.7 0.0) (112040.0 -34649.7 0.0) (112098.0 -34641.7 0.0) (112134.0 -34649.7 0.0))

(setq yCord (y_cord_accend lTemp))
((112000.0 -34881.7 0.0) (111946.0 -34801.7 0.0) (112000.0 -34773.7 0.0) (112040.0 -34649.7 0.0) (112134.0 -34649.7 0.0) (112004.0 -34641.7 0.0) (112098.0 -34641.7 0.0))

(setq zCord (z_cord_accend lTemp))
((111946.0 -34801.7 0.0) (112000.0 -34881.7 0.0) (112000.0 -34773.7 0.0) (112098.0 -34641.7 0.0) (112134.0 -34649.7 0.0) (112004.0 -34641.7 0.0) (112040.0 -34649.7 0.0))

(cord_sort_accend lTemp 0 T)
((112134.0 -34649.7 0.0) (112098.0 -34641.7 0.0) (112040.0 -34649.7 0.0) (112004.0 -34641.7 0.0) (112000.0 -34881.7 0.0) (112000.0 -34773.7 0.0) (111946.0 -34801.7 0.0))
```